# I have questions about **man’s pecs on full display** and **guy** in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, paraphrasing

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter. Even if a work-a-day guy doesn’t wear Perry Ellis clothes, he probably recognizes the name from those times he has wandered through a department store looking to stock up on dress shirts. Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass. And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a wide swath of men. Board shorts, crewneck sweaters, lean — but not tight — suits. Rich colors but nothing too psychedelic.
>
> Much of what Maccari put on the runway might actually have been better appreciated in a more intimate setting where audience members are able to put their hands on the fabric, see the details up close. But putting Perry Ellis on the runway during the inaugural season of New York Fashion Week: Men’s, served a larger purpose. It sent a message: This, too, is fashion. And there’s nothing to fear.
>
> Perry Ellis lends a helping hand by showing a **guy** just how to wear one of those sheer shirts that designers are putting on the runway, with a **man’s pecs on full display** .He should wear it with the easy élan of a T-shirt: casually, understated. With shorts.

1. Who the word **guy** is reffering to? The model walking on the runway? Or the average person watching the show?
2. Could you simplify the phrase **man's pecs** ? What does **pecs** mean here?
3. How would you paraphrase **on the full display** ?

Comment: Posts need to have only one question per post. You are asking three different questions here.

Answer (score 3):

The term "guy" refers to the consumer, the average person watching the show. The phrase "pecs" refers to pectoral muscles, which lie under the chest. So a simplification might be "pectorals" or merely "chest," though this latter phrase loses some of the meaning.  "On full display" might be paraphrased as "clearly visible" or "there for the whole world to see."